# Rails reorder on join based on two fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the code:

```
 scope :workflow_sort, ->{ has_content.joins(:client).reorder(:clients => :position, :projects => :position) }
```

for ordering two objects in a join via an association. `Client` is the parent and has many `Projects`. Both have the attribute `position`. I'm trying to sort the join by the `Client Position` then the `project position`

When using the code above I get a `Direction "position" is invalid. Valid directions are: [:asc, :desc, :ASC, :DESC, "asc", "desc", "ASC", "DESC"]` as seen in the screenshot. How do I change this to effectively do the same with `ASC` for each position?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [ActiveRecord QueryMethods](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/reorder)

> ```
> User.order('email DESC').reorder('id ASC').order('name ASC')
> ```
>
> generates a query with ‘ORDER BY id ASC, name ASC’.

So in your case it should be

```
scope :workflow_sort, -> { has_content
                             .joins(:client)
                             .reorder('clients.position ASC')
                             .order('projects.position ASC') }
```

or

```
scope :workflow_sort, -> { has_content
                             .joins(:client)
                             .reorder(:clients => :position)
                             .order(:projects => :position) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually [reorder](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/reorder) is used when there is some existing order on your relation and you want to replace that existing order by the new order.
But, if you don’t have any order (or scopes) defined on the relation, you can just use order:

```
scope :workflow_sort, -> { has_content.joins(:client).order('clients.position asc, projects.position asc') }
```

But, if you have any pre-existing order on your relation, then use reorder once to replace the current order with the new one, and then more subsequent order chain calls to order by more attributes:

```
scope :workflow_sort, -> { has_content.joins(:client).reorder('clients.position asc').order('projects.position asc') }
```